# how to modify file using T4 template

Tags: c#, t4

I want to update my app.xaml.cs file from

```
NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);
```

to

```
NavigationService.Navigate("Hub", null);
```

using T4 template. Is it possible? or is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding T4 badly. T4 templates `generate` files from a certain input, they don't `modify` existing files.

Comment: Thanks HighCore for your instant reply... Actually I am generating some files using T4 template. but now need a way to modify existing files.. any other way to do it? Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you are generating files using T4 you should *never* edit the result. If you need to inject specific behavior use partial classes and methods. If you never edit the result of T4 you just regenerate without need to worry about merging with manual changes.

Comment: Thanks FuleSnabel, my requirement is I am making itemtemplate and for that I have one wizard and once user select checkbox, I want to update the app.xaml.cs file and update start page from Main to Hub.. Thanks in advance